# Can the derivation of the differentiation of inverse trig functions without using inverse or implicit function theorems be done?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If we take the derivative of a typical inverse function we will end up with *one divided by the square root of one minus x squared.* As for example let us use the inverse of simply the sin x.  Here is an example which I can easily follow. I will provide a link, it is much better than my graphics can do:

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/DiffInvTrigFcns.aspx

You will notice that it invokes the Inverse Function Theorem stated in the beginning which I believe the Implicit Function Theorem can be used to proof this.

I am wondering if differentiating a typical inverse trig function can be done without invoking the IFT.  I suspect not but the proof of IFT is not usually given in typical first semester multivariable calculus classes even though differentiating inverse trig function is standard fair. Just curious.

Comment: The argument given on that page doesn't explicitly mention the inverse function theorem at all. *If* $y = \arcsin x$ is known to be differentiable, the stated argument applies the chain rule to $\sin y = x$ to obtain the formula. Are you asking why $y = \arcsin x$ is differentiable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the chain rule for the function of a function ie $$\frac d{dx}g(f(x))=\frac {df(x)}{dx}\frac {d g(f(x))}{df(x)}$$ and this is normally proved (though some care is required over conditions) alongside the other elementary results like the derivative of a product.

The way it works is this, for example: suppose $y=\arcsin x$ so that $x=\sin y$. We differentiate both sides of this second equation with respect to $x$ to obtain $$1=\frac {dy}{dx}\cos y=\frac {dy}{dx}\sqrt {1-x^2}$$ so that $$\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac 1{\sqrt {1-x^2}}$$Again care is required over conditions and things like the sign of the square root.

Comment: This works if you know that $y = \arcsin x $ is differentiable. I think that is the matter OP is asking about.

Comment: To add to Umberto's comment, at "*We differentiate both sides of this second equation with respect to x*", aren't you just using "implicit differentiation" (and so secretly appealing to the Implicit Function Theorem)?